# function template specialization is ignored

Tags: c++, templates

I have written a template function, which uses 2 other template functions (add & mul), in **math_functions.h** file :

```
template <typename Dtype>
Dtype mulvadd(Dtype* pa, Dtype* pb, int size, Dtype c)
{
    Dtype result = Dtype(0);
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        result = add<Dtype>(result, mul<Dtype>(pa[k],pb[k]));
    }
    result = add<Dtype>(result, c);
    return result;
}

int16_t mulv_int16(int16_t* pa, int16_t* pb, int size);
```

In **math_functions.cpp** i have different specializations for add & mul, but also specialization for mulvadd for int16_t type :

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fix16.h>
template<> float add<float>(float a, float b) { return a + b;}
template<> float mul<float>(float a, float b) { return a*b;}
template<> int16_t add<int16_t>(int16_t a, int16_t b) { return fix16_sadd(a, b); }
template<> int16_t mul<int16_t>(int16_t a, int16_t b) { return fix16_smul(a, b); }

#ifndef FIXMATH_NO_32BIT
template<> int16_t mulvadd<int16_t>(int16_t* pa, int16_t* pb, int size, int16_t c)
{
    return c + mulv_int16(pa, pb, size);
}
#endif

int16_t mulv_int16(int16_t* pa, int16_t* pb, int size)
{
   ....
}
```

I have also written a simple test program :

```
#include "math_functions.h"
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int16_t av[4] = {241,134};
    int16_t bv[4] = {-28, 7};
    int16_t res = mulvadd<int16_t>(av, bv, 2, 0);
    printf("res=%f\n", (double)res);
}
```

This code compiles without any errors, but the strange thing is that when i call **mulvadd** the invoked function is the default template defined in the h file and not the specialized version from the cpp file.
Any reason why is that happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler will not know about the specializations when it compiles the file with the `main` function. All it knows are what is in the header file.

*Declare* the specializations in the header file, so the compiler knows about them.

Comment: BTW, the specializations may be overloads instead (with the removal of `<Dtype>` in `mulvadd`).

Comment: thanks !
so i'm surprised i didn't get "multiple definition" error for mulvadd<int16_t>